# cat terminal , check usb removed (perror)?

Tags: c, terminal, usb, cat

For an assignment we have  to  create C program that functions similar to the cat command. The first hand-in requires it to mimic very minimal operations of cat....i.e print to output, redirect. The issue I'm having is that one requirement is to print an error in the case that an output file residing on a usb drive is lost, i.e usb pulled out whilst redirecting stdout to it.

How do I catch such an error, also how can perform a test-case for that particular error ??

Many Thanks....really have no idea

**UPDATE CODE TEMP**

```
 int main(){
    char c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
       putchar(c);
       // Ensure newly created file exists
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `fprintf()`, from the [man pages](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/):

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.

So:

1. store the size of the `char` array you will write into a variable `x`
2. if `fprintf()` is less than `x`, the writing was interrupted.
3. exit gracefully

EDIT:

There are 2 things I'm thinking of:

1: When `putchar()` fails, it indicates an error when writing to the file. Since writing one byte doesn't take very long, this should be unlikely since it will be in a safe state once the byte is written (or you assume).

You can do this like so

```
if(putchar(c) == EOF){
    //write error
}
```

2: If you're asked to quit the instant you detect a file removal, then you need to monitor the directory. Luckily, you're only looking at one directory. However that `while` loop gets in the way of things because `getchar()` is a blocking function (cannot return until something happens). You should use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to monitor the directory, then probably [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) to poll the file descriptor of `inotify()`. When I did this I used [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) because we were forced to.

Some kind of an idea how to monitor a directory with `inotify()`

```
int length, i = 0;
char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
memset(buffer, 0, EVENT_BUF_LEN*sizeof(char));
//init inotify
fd = inotify_init();
if(fd < 0){
    perror("inotify init");
}
//add directory to watch list
wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, path , IN_DELETE | 
    IN_DELETE_SELF | IN_MODIFY | IN_MOVE_SELF | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO);
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd, &fds);
//wait for event, since read() blocks
length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN );
if ( length < 0 ) {
    perror("zero event length");
}
struct inotify_event *event;
while (i < length){
    //cast the event to a char buffer
    event = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer[i];
    if (event->len){
        //this was a custom function of mine
        storeEvent(event);
    }
    i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
}
```

You'll have to check which attributes to use when adding a directory (like `IN_DELETE` or `IN_MODIFY`) since they will determine what triggers an `inotify()` event. Note this code will only detect one event, and blocks at the `read()` statement.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that fprintf creates a predefined file. What I have to achieve is for instance:
   `./Cat > redText` and this runs in a while loop until EOF is reached. Its in this process that I Have to ensure the created file still exists. Ive added a code template we got to the original question.
note that there are no command line arguements , getchar/putchar is used.

Comment: ok I think its doing what I intend to, I went ahead and added an if-else to check for `putchar(c) == EOF` in the while loop now, but how would I test this condition...is there a way to create a fake EOF

Comment: To make `putchar()` fail, run another C program that applies a lock on the file descriptor you're writing to with [lockf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/lockf) then run your original program.